# Dynamic Linq and use of Between

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

I am having a Dynamic Linq where It should perform comparison between two integers. I tried so many but none of them worked for me.

**Code**

```
db.Bibs.Where(" Id >=  1 && Id<1000 ")
db.Bibs.Where(" Id between  1 && 1000 ")
```

How to form this string to make it work. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is SQL Server, it doesn't understand && use AND instead:

```
db.Bibs.Where(" Id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 ")
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library